# How to use count in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get data and count feature to show up on the client-side by calling - api/test/name=storm, but I a unable to see any count result, only data on the client end.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] Query query)
    {
        var data = db.database.AsQueryable();
        int page = 0;
        int pageSize = 10;

        if (query.name != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.Name == query.name);
        }
        if (query.cusip != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.CUSIP == query.cusip);
        }

        if (!data.Any())
        {
            var message = string.Format("No data was found");
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
        }
        if (query.name != null)
        {
            data = data.OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate).Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        }
        if (query.cusip != null)
        {
            data = data.OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate).Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        }

        int SelectedRows = data.Count();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
        Console.Write("{0}records displayed of {0} found.", SelectedRows);
    }

}
```

Output response:

```
 [{"$id":"1","ID":419035,"Name":"ACIS 2013-1A E","SaleDateTime":null,"Region":null,"CUSIP":"00089PAA6","Size__m_":"2500000","OriginalRating":null,"MaturityDate":null,"Manager":null,"priceTalk":"92-24","Cover":"TALK","LastUpdated":"2013-08-01T09:06:37","UploadDate":"2013-07-31T00:00:00","Type":"CLO","ISINs":null,"Decimal_price":92.75,"CMBS_spread":null,"CMBS_decimal":null,"Current_size":"2500000"},
```

Could someone please direct me to the correct approach, if this is not inadequate approach to the count function. Many thanks.

Comment: We need to know what formatters you have configured and what the client code looks like.  What media type are you trying to return?

Comment: I am returning data in json format. I have attached an sample response in the above post as requested. Any help or guidance much appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: try `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,new {SelectedRows, data });`

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion.  I able to get count value on the client-end. I would like to be able show the count value in message on the client-end but when I try to implement the following logic below i get errors.    int SelectedRows = data.Count();
            var mes = string.Format("{0} found of results");
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { mes, SelectedRows, data });

Answer (score 0):

From your code you are not return the count. you should change the return statement to

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, SelectedRows );
```

Also since you are returning before the `Console.Write` call, you probably not see anything written to the console.

if you have something like

```
var data = [ {a:b, c:d}, {e:f, g:h, ...}, {..}, ... ]
```

in the client where data is an array of all the objects you are return from your c# method then you can do a

```
var count = data.length
```

in Javascript and get the number of objects you have returned. But in this case you don't need to do the count in your C# method.

Comment: Thank you for your response. this is would only give me numeric value of the count, i would like to be able to get message with the count values, representing the the rows found. Many thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Do you need the values as well as the count?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Apology for not clearing this up in my original post.

Comment: see my edit. If you really want to avoid the Javascript code I propose you can use the comment from Crundy.

Answer (score 0):

Your "SelectedRows" returns in Console only.

Try:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, SelectedRows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I can't up vote a comment... for what it's worth, I concur with Grundy in the comments on the original post... Returns not only the dataset, but the count of records in the dataset as the question asked requested.